# Sylius Overwrite SecurityController

Tags: overwrite, sylius

I find SecurityController in `"vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Controller\SecurityController.php"`

,no I overwrite it in `"src\AppBundle\Controller\Ui"` and define in app\config\services.yml:

```
services:
   sylius.controller.security:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\Ui\SecurityController
```

now, I get this error:

> (2/2) FileLoaderLoadException
>   Expected to find class "AppBundle\Controller\Ui\SecurityController" in file "/home/ftdev/host/shopex/b2c/unicef/src/AppBundle/Controller/Ui/SecurityController.php" while importing services from resource "../../src/AppBundle/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in /home/ftdev/host/shopex/b2c/unicef/app/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "/home/ftdev/host/shopex/b2c/unicef/app/config/config.yml").

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to config/services.yml, if there no same lines:

```
services:
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sylius.controller.security:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\Ui\SecurityController
    autowire: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```